# How can i print the result of command line in the HTML page using PHP?

Tags: php, apache

By Using backtics i can execute some command in the running machine like this -

```php
<?php
      echo `cd ~ && ls -al`
?>
```

Running this code in the CLI mode ( `php index.php` ) shows me the output as it should be displaying but how can i print the same thing in a HTML page.

do i have to enable something on `php.ini` ?? or else ??

I also tried this but doesn't  seems working on the Browser

```php
<?php
    echo shell_exec("cd ~ && ls -la")
?>
```

**Its Working on the CLI mode but not on the Browser**

Here is CLI mode output for the above script
[image]

Comment: try using shell_exec function of php

Comment: Not Working in the Browser

Comment: The backticks doesn't report execution errors, use `exec` and check the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to execute a command https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.shell-exec.php

It will return the output of the command, and null if an error occurred or if the command return nothing

When you run  a script from a web server, you inherit the user that run the web server permissions. Usually www-data for apache2. If you try to run a command without right permissions, shell_exec will return null.

You can try to use exec() if you want to see errors https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```php
exec('ls',$output);
var_dump($output);
```

Becareful, you should first invoke bash

```php
 shell_exec('/bin/bash -c "cd ~ && ls -la"')
```

Comment: Its Working on the Command Line but not in the Browser, probably something by default is turned off in the PHP.ini file

Comment: Have you any error when executing this function or it just does nothing ?

Comment: Maybe you try to run a command but the command fail because of your permission. When you use shell_exec, the command is run by the apache2 user. Which command are you running ?

Comment: No, NO Errors at all, Just blank page

Comment: But Its Working on the CLI mode.

Comment: Maybe you can try https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php exec method. 
exec('ls',$output);
var_dump($output);

Comment: In CLI mode you run the script with your own permission, not with the apache2 user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222783/discussion-between-john-clarkson-and-ypio).

Comment: the solution was to first invoke bash. I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$output = shell_exec( 'ls -l /abc_directory' );
var_dump ( $output );
```

It will depend on permission.For example, if your web server user like apache uses www-data has permission to access that particular directory like /abc_directory then you will see the output of the command, else nothing will be shown in the output.

In your screenshot When you are running on the cli using php command, you are running php as **user ace** ( I assume), but in browser it will be executed as web-server user www-data (apache) .

Comment: Showing NULL on the Screen

Comment: @JohnClarkson, I have added in the answer.